# Brute force md5 checksum matching regex

Tags: performance, beginner, go

The code starts with 128 bits of 0 (size of `md5sum` checksum) then brute forces to find checksum matching regex (all characters of checksum in hex are digits). I know that there may be collisions and that not all 2^128 possible checksums will come out.

I know that if the code is run, that it will not finish any time soon. I will try to read up on how I can change the `for` loop into a parallel `for` loop that uses all CPU cores.

This is one of my first (not very useful) programs in Golang. All constructive feedback welcome.

Output:

```
0000000000000000000000000092FE92    14275262221639818016075488414463
000000000000000000000000009FF5EA    56052719788687373369347657641554
00000000000000000000000000BA7A1D    25521851964074241922881283516897
00000000000000000000000000E13807    19356247379454983142782955697777
00000000000000000000000000E8C976    64115693827254722796959498140064
00000000000000000000000001037BAD    68461226587668825351060559236884
0000000000000000000000000109658F    87596081213274701373126754303410
...
```

````
package main

import (
    "crypto/md5"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    data := []byte("\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00")

    r, _ := regexp.Compile("^[0-9]{32}$")

    for {
        hash := md5.Sum(data)
        hash_hex_string := hex.EncodeToString(hash[:])

        if (r.MatchString(hash_hex_string)) {
            fmt.Printf("%X    %s\n", data, strings.ToUpper(hash_hex_string))
        }

        if (!increment(data, 15)) {
            break
        }
    }
}

func increment(data []byte, start_pos int) (bool) {
    if (start_pos < 0) {
        return false
    }

    data[start_pos]++

    if (data[start_pos] == 0) {
        return increment(data, start_pos - 1)
    }

    return true
}
```
````